# Can't get local notification based on location in time

Tags: swift, push-notification, location, ios17

Current goal is to get appropriate local notification when user will be in exact places(expected places I add to array). Unfortunately I always get notifications from time to time. As the example - I run application on my iPhone and simulate expected location - nothing happened, then I switch to another appropriate location - still nothing happened, and when I chose appropriate location third time - I get notification relates to first location, other one or two notification in pending status. Code example below.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import Foundation
import NotificationCenter


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var positionAlert:UIAlertController? = nil
    var ULocation:UserLocations?
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    let identifier = UUID().uuidString
    var usrAlrt:AlertNotification?
    let locList = locationList()
    let firstLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.0, longitude: 120.0)
    let secondLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 4.0, longitude: 12.0)
    
    
    @IBAction func btnAlrt(_ sender: Any) {
        print(ULocation!.locManager.location!)
        
    }
    
        //MARK: - Send changed location to local variable
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.list)
    }
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
            locList.locationAdd(location: firstLocation)
            locList.locationAdd(location: secondLocation)
            ULocation = UserLocations(locationManager: CLLocationManager(),Delegate: self)
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true) {
                    [self] timer in
                    if(locList.locatinFinder(location: ULocation!.locManager.location!.coordinate)){
                let long = ULocation!.locManager.location!.coordinate.longitude
                let lat = ULocation!.locManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
                        print("MATCHED")
            AlertNotification(region: CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long), radius: 30, identifier: identifier), delegate: self, identifier: identifier).scheduleNotification(notificationType: "\(ULocation!.locManager.location!)")
                        usrAlrt?.notificationCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { notif in
                            for notification in notif {
                                print(notification)
                            }
                        })   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I had read all possible documentations and tried implement all examples that I found, but still have the same problem.